# How to include two SET statement while querying data in mariadb

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb

Database - Mariadb,
Platform - Linux

Below code gives error : ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Set ENDTIME = STR_TO_DATE (@T2, '%m%d%Y%H%i%s')' at line 6.

```
   1 LOAD DATA LOCAL 
   2 INFILE '/home/test.txt' 
   3 INTO TABLE cdr FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
   4 (ID , APARTY , BPARTY , @T1, @T2, DURATION, INTG, OUTTG, INRC, OUTRC)
   5 Set STARTTIME = STR_TO_DATE (@T1, '%m%d%Y%H%i%s'),
   6 Set ENDTIME = STR_TO_DATE (@T2, '%m%d%Y%H%i%s');
```

Guessing the end of line 5 has some problem with comma. I am not sure how to include both the SET statements at a time.If i delete line 6, the code works fine.

Comment: Solved, by delete the 'Set' keyword on line 6

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to repeat the set keyword.

Set X = '', Y = '';